# Windows 7 directories stay read-only, even after they are changed to read-write

Tags: windows-7, windows, read-only

In my Windows 7 installation, some USB directories are read-only, and even after they are changed to read-write, checking their properties reveals that they are still read-only.
See [screen-shots](https://www.diigo.com/item/p/oooepprzcbsredsaczbecarosa).
I also used `D:\>attrib -r  d:\cygwin\tmp /S /D` from a *cmd* window, but it has the same results as from the GUI.

Any ideas how to debug/solve?

Comment: Is the USB drive itself hardware write protected? Does it have a little switch? If so, try setting that the other way.

Comment: @Roald van Doorn
There's no problem writing to the USB's directories from cygwin, so the problem is somewhere in the Windows OS configuration (that keeps these directories as read-only).